# Connect VBA to PostgreSQL

Tags: vba, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to a table via VBA from Autodesk Inventor.

I get the error shown below. The same code in Excel works.

I checked my project references, and they match. Searching on that error brings up some permissions-related issues. They seem to be linked to Excel. Are the methods I'm using exclusive to Excel?

[image]

```vb
Sub PostGresTest()

Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
' Connection Parameters
Dim strUsername As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strServerAddress As String
Dim strDatabase As String
' User:
strUsername = "TEST"
' Password:
strPassword = "password"
' Server Address:
strServerAddress = "localhost"
' Database
strDatabase = "postgres"

oConn.Open "DSN=PostgreSQL35W;" & _
  "Database=" & strDatabase & ";" & _
  "Uid=" & strUsername & ";" & _
  "Pwd=" & strPassword
.......
```

I omitted the rest of the code since the error occurs on the `oConn.Open` line.

Comment: Did you Instal PostgreSQL ODBC Driver in your machine https://odbc.postgresql.org/ ?

Comment: Yes - presumably this is why it works when I run the code in Excel?

Comment: I'm not sure, May excel VBA load some references by default that detect odbc.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to the code and my DSN settings then my PC rebooted overnight for a windows update. This morning, everything worked. I suggest it was probably the reboot that did it because it didn't work before rebooting, but maybe my settings were wrong anyway.

I found a Stack question that suggested that the DSN should be set up under 'System DSN' not 'User DSN' - (sorry - I lost the link) -So I made that change too.

Here's the final code:

```
Function PostGresTest(Optional StrSQL As String = "")

Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
' Connection Parameters
Dim strUsername As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strServerAddress As String
Dim strDatabase As String
' User:
strUsername = "TEST"
' Password:
strPassword = "password"
' Server Address:
strServerAddress = "localhost"
' Database
strDatabase = "postgres"
   
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};" & _
         "DSN=PostgreSQL35W;" & _
         "Database=" & strDatabase & ";" & _
         "SERVER=" & strServerAddress & ";" & _
         "Uid=" & strUsername & ";" & _
         "Pwd=" & strPassword
 .....
```